# Calling a Value in a List using While Loop

Tags: python, arrays, random, while-loop

is there any way to know if the previous appended value is greater than the newly appended value using while loop

```
unifarr = []
forwarr = []
while t :
unif = randint(-75, 75)  # To move face in every possible angle
forw = randint(-1, 1)  # Move every 1 pixel, -1 for back 1 for forward
t.left(unif)
t.forward(forw)
sleep(0.01)
forwarr.append(forw) 
unifarr.append(unif)# check if prev. value is < or > than newly appended value
```

i am using random that appends in an array is there any possible way to check if the previous appended random value is greater than the newly appended value

Comment: Please provide the complete code

Comment: assume `forwarr` is a list, you could do `if forwarrr[-1] > forw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your base case outside `while` loop and check whether the newly created number is greater than the base case or not. If greater, you do your stuff and finally set your previous to new number for future iterations. Something like this would do the job:

```
from random import randint

previous_forv = randint(-75, 75)
previous_unif = randint(-1, 1)
forwarr = [previous_forv]
unifarr = [previous_unif]

while t:
    new_forv = randint(-75, 75)
    new_unif = randint(-1, 1)

    t.left(unif)
    t.forward(forw)
    sleep(0.01)
    
    if new_forv > previous_forv:
        forwarr.append(new_forv)
        previous_forv = new_forv

    if new_unif > previous_unif:
        unifarr.append(new_unif)
        previous_unif = new_unif
```

Answer (score 1):

you can index using negative number to index the list from the other end. i.e with `-1` you will get the last value with `-2` second last value and so on.

```
if unif > unifarr[-1]:
   print ("is greater")
else:
  print ("is not greater")

unifarr.append(unif)
```

OR

```
unifarr.append(unif)

if unifarr[-1] > unifarr[-2]:
   print ("is greater")
else:
  print ("is not greater")
```